# What's an appropriate include_path PHP/PEAR setting for Macports?

Tags: php, pear, macports

I'm using Macports for my PHP development.  I *thought* that everything associated with Macports should be located under/opt/local, but I can't load the PEAR::Mail_Mime package I just installed through PEAR.  I did confirm that the path to pear is /opt/local/bin/pear, but I have no idea where it dumped the package files, so I don't know how to include them in my path.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pear files are typically installed in a share/php directory although I'm not on my mac right now so I can't check exactly where that might be.  You can find that directory using locate though.  From your terminal type:

```
$ locate PEAR.php
```

It should return something like `/usr/share/php/PEAR.php` - In this example `/usr/share/php` should be in my include path.  `Mail.php` and `Mail/mime.php` should also be in this directory.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. For the record, PEAR dropped the files into /usr/local/PEAR.  Doesn't make much sense to me, but as long as I know now.

Answer (score 3):

If you used the pear command to install the package, you could also do

```
$ pear list mail_mime
```

to get a listing of all files from that package and where they were installed to. It's a handy way of looking for example files, especially when used with `grep` ;-)